# Should we have a tag for ideas about safety improvements?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are quite a lot of questions that bring up an idea for improving the safety of commercial aviation, and ask why the idea is not implemented.

These questions tend to have similar answers: namely, that commercial aviation is already safe enough, and implementing the idea would provide a minuscule safety benefit (or would even make things worse) at significant expense.

Should we have a tag for all of these questions? Perhaps we could use [safety-idea](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety-idea).

These questions include:

- [Why are commercial flights not equipped with parachutes for the passengers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2186/why-are-commercial-flights-not-equipped-with-parachutes-for-the-passengers)
- [Why don't commercial jet aircraft have a break-apart, parachute escape system?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9243/why-dont-commercial-jet-aircraft-have-a-break-apart-parachute-escape-system)
- [Why not just drop an engine on fire?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33983/why-not-just-drop-an-engine-on-fire)
- [Why not increase the number of Flight Data Recorders and add jettisoning capability?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50816/why-not-increase-the-number-of-flight-data-recorders-and-add-jettisoning-capabil)
- [Why don't airliners carry radar jamming technology or missile counter measures?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/why-dont-airliners-carry-radar-jamming-technology-or-missile-counter-measures)
- [What reasons exist for not designing airplanes with breakaway wings for crash safety?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/what-reasons-exist-for-not-designing-airplanes-with-breakaway-wings-for-crash-sa)
- [Why don't big commercial planes have full aircraft parachutes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9564/why-dont-big-commercial-planes-have-full-aircraft-parachutes)
- [Why don't commercial aircraft adopt a slightly more seaplane-like design to allow safer ditching in case of emergency?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66587/why-dont-commercial-aircraft-adopt-a-slightly-more-seaplane-like-design-to-allo)
- [Why are movable rocket thrusters not used in airplanes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11584/why-are-movable-rocket-thrusters-not-used-in-airplanes)
- [Could ejector seats save lives in commercial aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52565/could-ejector-seats-save-lives-in-commercial-aircraft)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fail to see the benefit.

Either these questions are, as you stated, basically answerable with opinion - "Unlikely to be worth the weight gain" - which makes them bad questions.

Or, they are "I've had this great idea - do you agree its a great idea?" which are *also* bad questions in my humble opinion.

[safety-idea](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety-idea) (or something similar) has a whiff of meta-tag too. Does it stand on it's own? I do not think so. Is it a GA safety idea, or a commercial safety idea? Does it refer to helicopter operations or fixed wing? Some other tag would need to accompany it to make it a well-tagged question.